# How to scale up video with Python moviepy?

Tags: python, video, moviepy

I am using Python 3.10 and **moviepy** library to process videos. I need to **scale up** (zoom) video **without changing its resolution**. There are a lot of example of using moviepy *resize method*, but *it changes only the resolution*.

Are there any options of scaling video with moviepy or maybe you can suggest some solutions with openCV?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For achieving zoomed in video, we may combine **scaling and cropping**.

Example:

```
from moviepy.editor import VideoFileClip

clip = VideoFileClip("input.mp4")
width, height = clip.size
resized_and_cropped_clip = clip.resize(2).crop(x1=width//2, y1=height//2, x2=width*3//2, y2=height*3//2)
resized_and_cropped_clip.write_videofile("output.mp4")
```

- `resize(2)` - resize the video by a factor of 2 in each axis.
- `crop(x1=width//2, y1=height//2, x2=width*3//2, y2=height*3//2)` - crop a rectangle with the original image size around the center of the resized video.

---

Alternately we may first crop and then resize.
It is more efficient, but may result minor degradation at the frame's margins:

```
from moviepy.editor import VideoFileClip

clip = VideoFileClip("input.mp4")
width, height = clip.size
resized_and_cropped_clip = clip.crop(x1=width//4, y1=height//4, x2=width*3//4, y2=height*3//4).resize(2)
resized_and_cropped_clip.write_videofile("output.mp4")
```

---

The above examples show zoom in by a factor of x2.
For zooming by other factor, we have to adjust the computation of `x1`, `y1`, `x2`, `y2` arguments.